# I am trying to store current date and time in asyncstorage, but the return value I get is a promise and I can't see the values

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, asyncstorage

I tried passing the values as Json (key-pair values) but I don't get to to see the values in response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store current date and time in AsyncStorage you can use an async function,

```
StoreDate = async () => {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('date', new Date());
};
```

To retrieve stored date,

```
retrieveDate = async () => {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('date');
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Azin!! That did help me. I am getting the output as: value 2019-05-27T05:28:30.708Z. Can you help me out how can I convert/modify the date format?

Comment: Welcome @AbhirupMukherjee, please accept the answer

Comment: I am getting the output as: value 2019-05-27T05:28:30.708Z. Can you help me out how can I convert/modify the date format? @BanidAzin

Comment: you can convert it using the library moment. Refer official documentation (https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: i'm trying to store the date values while the state of app changes. And when the app is in background I want to store the date/time value in asyncstorage and return it. But the promise values all I get is undefined.. My RN version is 56.0. Can you help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show me the code. Doesn't know much about background working in RN, but I will try to look into that

Comment: Hi @BanidAzin if I am passing new Date().getTime() instead of new Date() in StoreDate method. I get an error saying: JSON Value '  '  of type NSNumber cannot be converted to NSString.

Comment: Any approach to solve this using parse or any other way? Please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem. please show me the code or make a snack. so I can check on that. sry for the late reply, I will reach out to you if I find anything.

Comment: Hi @BanidAzin I figured out the problem and it works fine. Thanks for your effort to help me out.

Comment: Hi,  That's great. @AbhirupMukherjee

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get value directly in a variable then you should use [Async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await)

then in your code you can get data like this

```
let data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('data');
```

to convert data to json

```
jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to resolve the promise:

```
getItem({ key: value}).then(data => console.log(data);
```

Comment: I tried resolving the promise by using filter. then((filter)=>{

        console.log("filter",filter);
        

      }); But  I can't see the values being stored/returned back in the response.